# asp.net mvc building url with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to a build a url in asp.net mvc but the object route values data come in later on through ajax. Basically what's happening is the following:

I click a button, which does an ajax call to the server to do some work. If the call is successful, I have to redirect to another page. I tried doing a redirect to action in the method but realized that won't work because it was ajax. So I decided to add the following in the success parameter to my ajax call:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("view", "controller", new { data=data })';
```

but obviously this is compiled (or built or whatever) into a string when the page initially renders, and my `data=data` part is where the data is coming in after the ajax call.

is there another way to incorporate the data into my url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL helper should give you the controller/action url on page render, then you can append the parameters using javascript like below.

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("view", "controller")?data='+data;
```

Comment: the data is coming back null in the controller action method. but in the ajax completion success call theres data

Comment: Can you paste the URL in the browser address bar when the redirection occurs?

Comment: never mind it worked thanks, I had the wrong data type in the parameter